Где находится ParseMode в aiogram?
from aiogram.types import ParseMode не работает:

ImportError: cannot import name 'ParseMode' from 'aiogram.types'


Вбиваем в гyгл «aiogram parsemode» и переходим по первой же ссылке...

@andreymal Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013)

@andreymal я посмотрел вашу ссылку и там нет ответа

@NickVolynkin https://i.sstatic.net/2p26B.jpg

@andreymal я прочел ваше сообщение уже раз 5, зачем вы продолжаете его спамить?

@Kromster потому что оно иногда пропадает

@andreymal а зачем вы их постоянно восстанавливаете то? Я прочел. Если вы хотите чтобы прочли другие, то не надо его адресовать мне - сделайте пост на Мете )

@andreymal хватит, достачно.

@aepot пока оно пропадает — не достачно

Если выбирать для каждого сообщения свой parse_mode, то:
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode
#  И где-то позже...
await message.answer("Hello, <b>world</b>!", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)

Но если хотите поставить дефолтный parse_mode, что бы не указывать его для каждого сообщения, можете поставить его по дефолту:
from aiogram.client.default import DefaultBotProperties
bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))

